# Sonarcloud review for Github repository failed

Tags: .net, github, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I am using sonarcloud for https://github.com/fatihyildirim1o/aspnet-starter-kit but it is not working because of below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBKQ8.png)

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is better to embed the error message as text, so Stack Overflow can better index the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `dotnet build` fail with this error message (line 26 on the capture in the question) :

> MSBUILD : error MSB1011 : Specify wich project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file

Nothing is build and SonarQube can't analyze.

In the CI task, you need precise the csproj or the sln. If you need build and analyze several project/solution, it's need several `dotnet build` instructions.

In you case, you can :

```sh
dotnet build "onion-architecture.sln"
```